# Is there a dig command to add a record to the dns server?

Tags: dig

I am writing a piece of a software to add a dns record, but first I want to sent adding of the record directly on the dns server. I can use dig to query, but what can I use to do a direct add?

Answer (score 0):

That depends on what software is running on the DNS server or if the DNS servers are a service provided by a third-party. In the case of the former it will vary and in the case of the latter they may have an API that will allow you to add records programatically.

Comment: Thanks, I am going through 3rd party API and I was able to do it. Though at the time I was looking at bypassing the API and going directly to the server.